# URL Routing Categories and Sub-Categories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, url-rewriting, url-routing

I've searched a long time for a resolution of my problem but I didn't found one..

I think, I'm not the only one who has this task and hope for an answer.

My website stores products.. many products. All these products have one or more categories (or subcategories). To retrieve a product in the correct category is not the problem. I will add the Id of this at the end of the product name like: http://localhost.com/products/details/books/romance/romeo-and-julia-3245. The controller is products and the action is details.

But what is the best solution to get clean URLs if I want to list all products of one category? The problem is, that one sub-category could be exist more then once. For example:

http://localhost.com/products/list/games/romance

http://localhost.com/products/list/books/romance

If I call the list action in the products controller, I cannot detect if the sub-categaory "romance" is related to games or books.

How can I solve this issue?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You may try to write 2 routes for `ActionResult List` and use parameters: if `ActionLink` contains parameter called `games` it takes route `"Games"`, if `books` - it takes route `"Books"`

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Games",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/games/romance",
                defaults: new { controller = "products", action = "List", games = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Books",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/books/romance",
                defaults: new { controller = "products", action = "List", books = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

I'm not sure it fits your needs, but you can play with this logic.

Comment: Hey, thank's for you comment. The problem is more the sub-categories. More sub-categorys could have same named sub-categorys. I need to identifier the categorys, but the solution with an id isn't seo clean right?